# Transportation optimization with collaboration between companies - Mathematical Modelling

Tags: mathematical-optimization, modeling, ampl

I am taking a course that utilizes mathematical modeling and am working on a model for optimizing transportation routes. In the problem, we are given the sets C (all transportation companies in the problem), I (all supply points available for all companies), and J (all demand points available for all companies). The companies manufacture an identical good, so there is the possibility for collaboration between companies to satisfy each other's demand points. Any combination of supply points and demand points is possible, and we know which supply/demand points belong to each company (I assume there is no overlap here). All demand should be satisfied.

- w(i,j) is the flow between supply point i and demand point j (the number of units of product transported on one trip driven from i to j)
- e(i,j) is the unit cost of the flow between supply point i and demand point j

I have figured out the following:

Objective function: [Minimize the total cost of all flows between supply point i and demand point j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU9Nl.png)

Constraints:

[The sum of all flows from supply point i to demand point j must be less than or equal to the supply capacity at point i, for all i in I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWmbz.png)

[The sum of all flows from supply point i to demand point j must equal the amount of demand at demand point j, for all j in J](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6opRS.png)

And a non-negativity constraint which mandates that the flows for all supply points i to demand points j must be non-negative.

However, there are additional constraints that I am having a hard time modelling (I have no prior experience in mathematical modelling previous to this course). The last requirement is that there should be at most two different companies delivering to demand points of another company, in addition to itself. How would I incorporate something like this into the model? My confusion is over the fact that only two companies can supply goods to a demand point if those companies do not include the company operating the demand point, and three companies if the original company is also supplying. For example, companies A, B, and C can supply to a demand point for company A. However, companies B, C, and D cannot supply to this same demand point. Is there a way to incorporate this type of indexing into the problem?

As a side note, I would also be very appreciative of any suggestions of textbooks that go over these type of mathematical modelling approaches from the basics. So far, the course has operated on the assumption that the students are somewhat familiar with mathematical modelling, which I am not.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> My confusion is over the fact that only two companies can supply goods
>   to a demand point if those companies do not include the company
>   operating the demand point, and three companies if the original
>   company is also supplying. For example, companies A, B, and C can
>   supply to a demand point for company A. However, companies B, C, and D
>   cannot supply to this same demand point. Is there a way to incorporate
>   this type of indexing into the problem?

The details will vary depending on how you've implemented the problem, but here's an example of how it might be coded in AMPL. (I haven't had a chance to test this code, so it may be a little buggy.)

The key is using information about supply/demand point ownership to define a sum that does not include companies supplying to their own points.

```
set SupplyPoints;
set DemandPoints;
set Companies;
set SupplyPointsByCompanies dimen 2 within {SupplyPoints,Companies};
# a set of (supply point, company) tuples. Following code assumes that
# each supply point has only one owning company.
set DemandPointsByCompanies dimen 2 within {DemandPoints,Companies};
# similarly for demand
param biggestsupply;
# to be defined as the largest value that any one point could supply to any other

var Supply{i in SupplyPoints, j in DemandPoints} >= 0;
# actual amount to be supplied from i to j
var PosSupply{i in SupplyPoints, j in DemandPoints} binary;
subject to DefinePosSupply{i in SupplyPoints, j in DemandPoints}: PosSupply[i,j]*biggestsupply >= Supply[i,j];
# forces PosSupply to equal 1 if Supply is non-zero

subject to limit_num_suppliers{(j,co) in DemandPointsByCompanies}:
    sum{j in SupplyPoints: (i,co) not in SupplyPointsByCompanies} PosSupply[i,j] <= 2;
```

Depending on the scale of your decision variables, you may need to play with tolerance settings to avoid some weirdness where PosSupply = 0 but biggestsupply*PosSupply is considered non-zero; see [this forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/3O7DsZuXIi4) for details.